# Using live_settings in python shell

Tags: python, django

I have 2 settings file (settings.py for my localserver) and (live_settings.py for my live_server).

Starting the shell using python manage.py shell in cmd

When i start the shell in my command prompt it takes settings.py by default, how can i set it to live_settings.py and then start the python shell.

Comment: Can you show us the code that does the imports?

Comment: I have my settings.py and live_settings.py in the D:>project folder.

Comment: when i start the cmd i go to this location and do python manage.py shell

Comment: i takes the settings.py by default whereas i want it to take live_settings.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start a normal shell (i.e. just typing `python` in your projct directory rather than using the `manage.py` helper). and manually set it up with your Django config like so

```
import live_settings
from django.core.management  import setup_environ
setup_environ(live_settings)
```

This worked for me. I've not used Django in a while now so things might have changed.

Alternatively, you could pass the `live_settings.py` as the parameter to the `--settings` option to `manage.py`. So

```
python manage.py --settings=live_settings shell
```

You can also simply set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable to the name of the `live_settings.py` module and launch `manage.py` with that. Remember that for the last two approaches, you need to pass the module name as Python would understand it rather than the file name.